# eclipse search with regular expression for words starting with lower case followed by upper case

Tags: eclipse

I want to search for a string which starts with a single small case letter followed by a capital letter. Like **aS**tring or **aS**Tring.

I tried with the regular expression `^[a-z][A-Z]*` from eclipse file search with regular expression as ticked, but that isn't getting the desired result.

Comment: Character `*` refers to zero or more characters in regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `\b[a-z][A-Z][a-zA-Z]*` and enable Regular Expressions in the *Find*-Window.
The `\b` is a word boundary, which works better than the `^` you used, because it matches the beginning of a "word" (somewhat blurry term in this context) and not the whole string (your code).
Also, the pattern you used would only find strings that start with a lower case letter and continue with only upper case letters.

Answer (score 0):

@mumpitz's answer works except that (as @Ab_sin rightly pointed out) he missed mentioning that the `Case sensitive` checkbox in the `find window` is also needed.
So that:

the regular expression pattern is: \b[a-z][A-Z]* (\b stands for word boundary)
And `Regular Expression` and `Case sensitive` checkboxes need to be checked